# How to get the user input in an incomplete Django form field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms

I have a "survey" form which has fields - name, id and age. I would like to capture the user entry in the "id" field before the user submits the form for scanning the entered "id" in my database table. How can I capture this entered data and use it in my view function for scanning the database? Can I use javascript to pass the user input to my view function? How would that look like? I am a newbie in Django development so any suggestions would help me big time!

Here is the view function I am trying to design that scans the "id" from my survey table and if there is a match in the past 30 days, then it returns an alert pop up to the user to take the survey or not.

```
def search(request):
if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
    form = TopicForm(request.GET) # A form bound to the POST data
    if form.is_valid():
        x = form.cleaned_data['id']
    else:
        x = form.cleaned_data['id']
x = request.POST.get('url')



posts = survey.objects.filter('id'=x)
posts1 = survey.objects.filter(date=posts)
delta= date.today - posts1

if delta.days <=30:
    return HttpResponse('Survey NOT required')            

else:
    return HttpResponse('Survey required')
```

**SURVEY TEMPLATE FORM.HTML**

```
  <form action="{% url 'FCR1' %}" method='post' id="form" class="table">


    {% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy form %}
    <br />
    <center> <button> SAVE RECORD &rsaquo;</button></center>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TopicForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Get user id from form data (maybe this is named 'user_id'?)
            id = form.cleaned_data['id']
            # Get the past 30 from today
            past_30_days = date.today() - timedelta(days=30)
            # Create the query, but not evaluate yet
            posts = Survey.objects.filter(id=id, date__gte=past_30_days)

            # Proper way to check if something exists or not
            if post.exists():
                return HttpResponse('Survey NOT required')
            return HttpResponse('Survey required')
        else:
            # form is not valid. Handle this approprietly.
            pass
```